# How can I get a gradle 5 precompiled script plugin get to work when it is in a package

Tags: gradle

I want to modularize my `build.gradle.kts` files by using the [precompiled script plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#kotdsl:precompiled_plugins) feature introduced with gradle 5.3.1.

It works fine when I have my simple `hello-world.gradle.kts` file in `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin` directly

```
tasks.register("hello-world") { println("hello world") }
```

and include it in the plugins section of my main `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
   `hello-world`
}
```

I can now use `gradle hello-world` and see the expected output.

But when I place the same script in `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/custom/hello-world-custom.gradle.kts` (adding `package custom` to the script) it fails, although the documentation states:

> Likewise, src/main/kotlin/my/java-library-convention.gradle.kts would result in a plugin ID of my.java-library-convention as long as it has a package declaration of my.

The main `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
   `custom.hello-world-custom`
}
```

but instead, I get an error:

```
 Script compilation error:

  Line 3:   `custom.hello-world-custom`
        ^ Unresolved reference: `custom.hello-world-custom`
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

**Update**: to reproduce this, I created a [small repo](https://github.com/jangalinski/gradle-precompiled-scripts) with different "hello world" tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was not quite clear from the docs, but I found the solution:

The package has to be defined outside the backticks:

```
plugins {
 `hello-world`
 custom.`hello-world-custom`
}
```